# How do I use JS to execute a heavy PHP function after the page loads in order to speed things up?

Tags: javascript, ajax, performance, asynchronous

I've got a web page that displays some content.  The query itself is pretty slow (4000 ms).

I don't want my users to have to wait for the query to run before the rest of the page loads though.

Is there a way I can stick some code before and after the  tag in my HTML template that will "delay" that function from executing until after everything else has rendered?

e.g.:

```
<javascript code that tells the page not to render what comes next until very last>

<?php my_heavy_php_function(); ?>

</javascript>
```

Comment: Sounds like you're not optimizing the bottleneck.  I'd examine the query first.  There should be a number of ways to improve a 4000 ms query.

Comment: I would normally agree with you, except this is a Drupal-powered query, aka, it's pretty tricky to get under the hood and mess with it.

Comment: not a fan of drupal or any other 'heavy' CMS for this reason.

Answer (score 2):

As I can understand from your question, you should go for AJAX: you first load the page without the heavy content, and when the page is ready you do an AJAX call to a webservice to fetch and display the data, while showing a "Processing, please wait" message to the user.

Answer (score 0):

symbolic write:
document.onload = ajax call

Answer (score 0):

### Using Ajax

Using the [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) request method you can post the email data to a script (submit.php).  The `$(function(){ });` executes when the dom is ready.  Also, you might need to use the 'timeout' option if you are going to be executing an long query.

*note* - I would suggest utilizing the ajax Response Object to make sure the script executed successfully.

```
$(function() {
   $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'submit.php',
      timeout: 10000,
      error: function()
      {
         alert("Request Failed");
      },
      success: function(response)
      {  
         //response being what your php script echos.
      }
   });
});
```

Although, jQuery is by no means required do do an ajax request, I would highly recommend using some kind of framework to help ensure x-browse support.

If you are using a large dataset I would highly recommend using json to encode your repsonses.  It makes parsing quite easy.  Here's an example with jQuery [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) API and likewise how you can [encode it with PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Answer (score 0):

Either optimizing the query or doing an AJAX call. Here is a plain JS way of doing AJAX, I found this script in a Google search and modified to use a callback function so you can parse the data or do other things other than just load the content straight to a HTML element:

the ajax function:  [The Original function I found unmodified](http://www.ajaxlines.com/ajax/stuff/article/simple_ajax_javascript_function.php)

```
function ajaxRequest(Url, callback) {
  var AJAX;
  try {
      AJAX = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  catch (e) {
      try {
          AJAX = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      }
      catch (e) {
          try {
              AJAX = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
          catch (e) {
              alert("Your browser does not support AJAX.");
              return false;
          }
      }
  }
  AJAX.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (AJAX.readyState == 4) {
          if (AJAX.status == 200) {
              callback(AJAX.responseText);
          }
          else {
              alert("Error: " + AJAX.statusText + " " + AJAX.status);
          }
      }
  }
  AJAX.open("get", Url, true);
  AJAX.send(null);
}
```

Usage of it:

```
<div> some normal content </div>
<div id="loadlater">loading data...</div>
<div> more content that loads before the data</div>

<script>
  ajaxRequest('/echo/html/', function( response) {
    document.getElementById('loadlater').innerHTML = response;;   
  });
</script>
```

Working example here: [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/subhaze/uu2HE/)

Comment: I'm afraid this will execute before the DOM is loaded (hence jquery)

Comment: You don't have to use jQuery for everything. Simply placing the calling method within a script tag below the div would work. I'll update my example...